# Google font not being loaded in SVG mask definition

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts, font-face

Wanting to make a logo, I started playing with SVG, and stuck trying to figure out how to use a Google Fonts family in a mask definition. If you want to reproduce, try loading the following .svg contents up in Google Chrome 85. The font loads fine for the second text element, but the first one (used in `#mask`) fails and defaults to `serif`.

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="256" height="256" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script:400');
    </style>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="256" height="256" stroke-width="0" fill="white" />
      <text font-size="128" x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="black" style="font-family: 'Dancing Script';">T</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="128" stroke-width="0" fill="red" mask="url(#mask)" />
  <text font-size="128" x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="black" style="font-family: 'Dancing Script';">T</text>
</svg>
```

It looks like this,

[image]

So yea. I mean, am I not supposed to refer to external font families in other definitions or something? Any way to get around this?

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome 85 on Win10 and it worked for me.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau How are you opening it? I just tried it with Chrome 85 on Windows 10, to no avail. Same problem as on Catalina.

Comment: I am just running the snippet. I just see the black T.  If I hide the corresponding `<text>` element, I see the expected masked hole of the same shape.

Comment: Alright.. So apparently loading a `.svg` file in Chrome directly causes the issue. Embedding it in a `.html` file directly worked fine.

Comment: Are you loading the SVG as an `<img>`?  If so, then having an external font will not work.  FIles loaded via an `<img>` must be self-contained. They cannot load third party files. It is a browser privacy restriction.  To work around that, you will need to include the font as a Data URL (ie: `data:`)

Comment: I literally just double clicked it, loading it directly. I get the whole security issue. What I don't get is how the font is loaded fine for the regular `<text>` element, but not the one in the `<mask>` element when loading the `.svg` directly, as opposed to embedding it in `.html`.

Comment: Privacy restrictions also apply to `file:` URLs.  So if you load the file directly from the file system, then the same thing will happen.  If it is served from a web server (`http://`) I would expect it to be fine.

Comment: I mean that doesn't really address why loading the `.svg` file directly still loads the font, but only for the `<text>` element not in `<mask>`. Watching the network tab I can see it call `https://fonts.googleapis.com/`, despite using the `file:` protocol. I already tried with a `SimpleHTTPServer`, literally the same issue. Still makes an external call, only displays the font in the non-masked text element. What happens if you try to load a `.svg` file directly with the `file:` protocol or through local HTTP?

Comment: Yeah. You're right. That explanation makes no sense.  If you're making a logo, I'd recomment that you don't rely on `<text>` elements anyway.  Convert the text to a path so that it can be used anywhere and renders the same everywhere.